# Best way to make argument parser accept absolute number and percentage?

Tags: python, argparse, nagios

I am trying to write a Nagios style check to use with Nagios. I have working script that takes in something like `-w 15 -c 10` and interprets that as "Warning at 15%, Critical at 10%". But I just realized that in the built-in Nagios plugins, the same arguments would mean "Warning at 15MB, Critical at 10MB"; I would instead need to enter `-w 15% -c 10%` to get the above behavior.

So my question is, what is the best way to make my script behave like the built-in Nagios scripts? The only way I can think of is accepting the argument as a string and parsing it, but is there a neater way?

Comment: Whether you can parse it in a custom `type` function, or have to do it after, depends on the details of the parsing.  Explain what output you want from the parsing.  Do you just divide by 100 in the % case, and multiply by 10^6 in the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own class as type for the arguments:

```
import argparse

class Percent(object):
    def __new__(self,  percent_string):
        if not percent_string.endswith('%'):
            raise ValueError('Need percent got {}'.format(percent_string))
        value = float(percent_string[:-1]) * 0.01
        return value

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="with percent")
parser.add_argument('-w', '--warning', type=Percent)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--critcal', type=Percent)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.warning)
```

Output:

```
python parse_percent.py  -w 15%
0.15

python parse_percent.py  -w 15
usage: parse-percent.py [-h] [-w WARNING] [-c CRITCAL]
parse-percent.py: error: argument -w/--warning: invalid Percent value: '15'
```

### Version that works with percent or MB

```
class Percent(object):
    def __new__(self,  percent_string):
        if percent_string.endswith('%'):
            return float(percent_string[:-1]), 'percent'
        else:
            return float(percent_string), 'MB'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="with percent")
parser.add_argument('-w', '--warning', type=Percent)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--critcal', type=Percent)

args = parser.parse_args()
value, unit = args.warning
print('{} {}'.format(value, unit))
```

Output:

```
python parse_percent.py -w 15
15.0 MB
python parse_percent.py -w 15%
15.0 percent
```

Comment: Well, the behavior of the Nagios script is such that `-c 15` means 15 MB and `-c 15%` will mean 15%. It takes in both. Ideally, is there a way to make argparse take in different types for the same flag, and have Python decide the right type based on what data it gets?

Comment: I think it is better to write the `percent` type as a plain function.  `__new__` (as opposed to `__init__` is normally only used when the class definition requires some special behavior.  Here is just seems to make the class behave like a plain function.

Comment: `@DDauS` - deciding between the `MB` and the `%` meaning is the job of this custom `type` function.  It takes a string, and returns something.  What it returns is for you to decide.

Comment: I'd like to use that with `action="append_const"` to store a list which apparently doesn't allow to have `type` argument. Any workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the `type` function which I believe behaves the same as `@Mike's` class:

```
def percent(astr):
    if astr.endswith('%'):
        return float(astr[:-1]), 'percent'
    else:    
        return float(astr), 'MB'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="with percent")
parser.add_argument('-w', '--warning', type=Percent)
parser.add_argument('-c', '--critcal', type=percent)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

testing:

```
1058:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py 
Namespace(critcal=None, warning=None)

1059:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py -w 14 -c 14
Namespace(critcal=(14.0, 'MB'), warning=(14.0, 'MB'))

1059:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py -w 14% -c 14%
Namespace(critcal=(14.0, 'percent'), warning=(14.0, 'percent'))

1059:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py -w bad
usage: stack41741065.py [-h] [-w WARNING] [-c CRITCAL]
stack41741065.py: error: argument -w/--warning: invalid Percent value: 'bad'

1100:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py -c bad
usage: stack41741065.py [-h] [-w WARNING] [-c CRITCAL]
stack41741065.py: error: argument -c/--critcal: invalid percent value: 'bad'
```

`type` just has to be a callable that takes a string, and returns a value.  Here it is returning a tuple, which the `store` Action just puts in the `namespace`.  If the callable returns a ValueError, TypeError or `argparse.ArgumentTypeError`, the error display should be the same.   In these examples the initial error is the ValueError produced by `float('bad')`.  The default error message is uses the callable's name (`Percent` v `percent`).

An example of post-parsing parsing is:

```
if args.o is not None:
    try:
        args.o = percent(args.o)
    except ValueError:
        parser.error('invalid args.o value')
print(args)

100:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py
Namespace(critcal=None, o=None, warning=None)
Namespace(critcal=None, o=None, warning=None)

1107:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py -o 14
Namespace(critcal=None, o='14', warning=None)
Namespace(critcal=None, o=(14.0, 'MB'), warning=None)

1107:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py -o 14%
Namespace(critcal=None, o='14%', warning=None)
Namespace(critcal=None, o=(14.0, 'percent'), warning=None)

1107:~/mypy$ python3 stack41741065.py -o bad
Namespace(critcal=None, o='bad', warning=None)
usage: stack41741065.py [-h] [-w WARNING] [-c CRITCAL] [-o O]
stack41741065.py: error: invalid args.o value
```

`argparse.FileType` is an example of a `type` function factory class.